# What's the best practice for handling old events when generating subscribable ICS files?

Tags: icalendar

I have a script whose output is an ICS file that my friends and I subscribe to in our various calendar applications.

The script generates a "fresh" calendar each time, and only has events that take place in the future.

Since this script is only for my personal use I am not overly concerned, but it make think - Is this poor practice?

If I had my script parse the ICS file, add new events, and then write it back to the file, would it not grow very large over time, and with more and more users over time it will cost more in terms of bandwith.

How do the professionals handle this? What is considered best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is a 'best practice'.

Google always issues the old events and I don't think has an option for future events only.  This can be very annoying - the whole lot has to be parsed!

Some apps allow one to request future events only.

I think apps do what makes sense for their calendars.  If it's a calendar of upcoming fixtures, do they really need the history?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a REST-based backend using ical4j, I faced the same problem.
I looked at various providers of ICS information.

All of them provided events within a one-year range, including all old events. This has the up-point, that the ICS file does not change frequently and can be cached.

Sure, the file has to be parsed, but transmission time (or lack thereof, due to caching) is dominating.